# stuck on "Operating system not found" screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, bios, grub

So I was dual booting windows and lubuntu on my acer laptop. I wanted to swap lubuntu for Linux mint so I deleted the Lubuntu partitions. I'm pretty sure I deleted something I wasn't supposed to because when I set my bios boot order, it was overwritten by grub2 and said "operating system not found" I tried switching from uefi to legacy bios, switching my boot order but it keeps booting no matter what to operating system not found. I have no idea what I'm supposed to do or if I destroyed my machine, but any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Boot a Linux Mint install disk/USB. See if you can still see important files on your Windows partition. Backup files (just to be sure) and Install Linux Mint.

Linux Mint should install its own version of grub, and allow you to boot into Windows again.

Comment: Well that's my main problem. I can't boot from a USB and one thing I just tried that wasn't mentioned in my post was that I opened the boot menu, but for some reason when I select a boot medium it doesn't do anything so I'm basically stuck.